# Angular lazy load with parent route parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a `ProfileModule` with the following routing :

```
// profile-routing.module

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProfilePageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'feed',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'feed',
        component: NewsFeedComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'gallery',
        component: MediasGalleryComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

It works as follow:

1. `ProfilePageComponent` fetches the profile ID in routing parameters and sends it to a `ProfilePageService`
2. `NewsFeedComponent` and `MediasGalleryComponent` receive the profile ID from `ProfilePageService`

Now, these two pages **have been moved into two separate modules** (respectively `NewsModule` and `MediasModule`), that I want to be **lazy loaded** in this routing. I cannot use ProfilePageService anymore. I came up with this solution :

```
// profile-routing.module

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProfilePageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'news/:id/feed', // same as the parent ID
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'news',
        loadChildren: () => import('./news/news.module').then(m => m.NewsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'medias',
        loadChildren: () => import('./medias/medias.module').then(m => m.MediasModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

// news-routing.module

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':profileId/feed',
  component: NewsFeedComponent
}];

// medias-routing.module

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':profileId/gallery',
  component: MediasGalleryComponent
}];
```

This solution is **not working**, since I cannot get the profile ID parameter from parent route. How can I avoid this problem ?

Moreover, I don't like the fact that profile ID is duplicated in the URL. What would be the Angular way to do things ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the child modules just see the path to their module as their root path, which does not include the `:id`. You can have a sharedService that is provided in your application root and reads the id on route changes. Then you can read that ID from within the child module.

```js
@Injectable()
export class RouterStateService {
  params$: Observable<Params>;
}
```

In your app component you can then do

```js
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private routerState: RouterStateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routerState.params$ = this.activatedRoute.params;
  }
}
```

And in your child-component/module you can use it as

```js
@Component(...)
export class WhatEverComponent {
  constructor(private routerState: RouterStateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routerState.params$.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

As always: Please do not forget to unsubscribe if you don't need the stream anymore.